# How to remove ArcSoft MediaImpression 2

Tags: uninstall, rundll32.exe, rundll

When using the unistaller found by Windows Configuration Panel > Uninstall programs I get the error:

RunDLL32: cannot find `C:\Program`

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an old program, I was unable to find the installer online (which often allows uninstalling).

I used the freeware version of Revo Uninstaller to try to uninstall, which failed again, but then allowed me to search for the registry values that match the software name.

If found that the variable `UninstallString` was interesting. I was able to copy it by exporting the search results to HTML using a right-click, then open the html in my web browser.

Here is the original broken UninstallString command:

```
RunDll32 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InstallShield\Engine\6\Intel 32\ctor.dll,LaunchSetup "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{7246B701-B0D2-4BB5-A290-8759E4201530}\Setup.exe" -l0x40c
```

I fixed this command by adding quotes around the path to ctor.dll, like this:

```
RunDll32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InstallShield\Engine\6\Intel 32\ctor.dll",LaunchSetup "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{7246B701-B0D2-4BB5-A290-8759E4201530}\Setup.exe" -l0x40c
```

Then I ran this fixed command inside cmd.exe executed as administrator and it worked :)